# Динамические запросы для системы фильтрации

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

Пишу модуль фильтрации. Есть вот такая `DTO`.

```
public class CarDTO {

private Long id;
private String name;
private Integer registrationYear;
private Double engineCapacity;
private Integer price;
private Integer numberOfSeats;
private TransmissionEnum transmission;
}
```

В контроллере создал `Get-метод` с несколькими `RequestParam` для фильтрации. Пока это выглядит вот так:

```
@GetMapping("/cars/")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<CarDTO>> findCar(
    @RequestParam(value = "minRegistrationYear") Long minRegistrationYear,
    @RequestParam(value = "maxRegistrationYear") Long maxRegistrationYear,
    @RequestParam(value = "engineCapacity") Long engineCapacity,
    @RequestParam(value = "engineCapacity") DriveEnum drive,
    @RequestParam(value = "numberOfSeats") Long numberOfSeats,
    @RequestParam(value = "transmission") TransmissionEnum transmission,
    @RequestParam(value = "MinPrice") Long minPrice,
    @RequestParam(value = "MaxPrice") Long maxPrice
) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(null);
}
```

Возникла проблема создания запроса, так как не все параметры могут быть выбраны. В таком случае, будет передаваться нулл и запрос будет выполняться некорректно.

Как и что использовать, чтобы избежать такого? На прошлом проекте использовали `TypedQuery`, но насколько понял сейчас это не очень востребовано.

Comment: Если вы используете spring-data-jpa, то попробуйте использовать Specification интерфейс. Пример можно найти здесь : https://leaks.wanari.com/2018/01/23/awesome-spring-specification/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос с помощью `Specification`.

Утильный объект:

```
public class CarSearch {

private Long minRegistrationYear;
private Long maxRegistrationYear;
private Long engineCapacity;
private DriveEnum drive;
private Long numberOfSeats;
private TransmissionEnum transmission;
private Long minPrice;
private Long maxPrice;
}
```

Сама спецификация:

```
public class CarSpecification implements Specification<Car> {

private final CarSearch criteria;

public CarSpecification(CarSearch criteria) {
    this.criteria = criteria;
}

@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Car> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery,
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

    final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    if (criteria.getMinRegistrationYear() != null) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder
            .ge(root.get("registrationYear"), criteria.getMinRegistrationYear()));
    }
    if (criteria.getMaxRegistrationYear() != null) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder
            .le(root.get("registrationYear"), criteria.getMaxRegistrationYear()));
    }
    if (criteria.getDrive() != null) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("drive"), criteria.getDrive()));
    }
    if (criteria.getNumberOfSeats() != null) {
        predicates
            .add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("numberOfSeats"), criteria.getNumberOfSeats()));
    }
    if (criteria.getTransmission() != null) {
        predicates
            .add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("transmission"), criteria.getTransmission()));
    }
    if (criteria.getMinPrice() != null) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.ge(root.get("price"), criteria.getMinPrice()));
    }
    if (criteria.getMaxPrice() != null) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.le(root.get("price"), criteria.getMaxPrice()));
    }
    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}
```